# How to pass binding to child view in the new NavigationStack.navigationDestination

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass a binding from a parent list view into a child detail view. The child detail view contains logic to edit the child. I want these changes to be reflected in the parent list view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ParentListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(0 ..< 5) { number in
                    NavigationLink(value: number) {
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                ChildDetailView(number: number) //Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Binding<Int>'

            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildDetailView: View {
    @Binding var number: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(number)")
            Button {
                number += 10
            } label: {
                Text("Add 10")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, I cannot pass number into ChildDetailView because it expects a binding. I have tried putting $ before number but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to make this work, or am I using the new NavigationStack completly wrong?

Answer (score 12):

Well, actually it is possible, but at first it is needed source of truth, i.e. state with data to bind to, and but in this case Binding will update only source, but not destination. It is more appropriate is to use `ObservableObject` view model in such case.

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Note: binding do not refresh `ChildDetailView` in such case - in can be used only for actions, but source is updated !!

Here is main part:

```
@State private var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  // << data !!
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach($numbers) { number in      // << binding !!
                NavigationLink(value: number) {
                    Text("\(number.wrappedValue)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Binding<Int>.self) { number in // << !!
            ChildDetailView(number: number)  // << binding !!
        }
    }
}
```

and a couple of extensions needed for Binding to transfer via navigation link value.

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/iOS16/TestBindingDestinationNavigationStack.swift)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the Binding extensions helped me a lot! One problem though: If I go to the ChildDetailView for a number and press the button "Add 10", nothing seems to happen. But if I go back to the ParentListView the value is correctly updated. How do I make the ChildDetailView refresh on button press?

Comment: I wrote about that in *Note* :) ... parent view does not update child view in this case (actually and it should not)... either map to local State or use ObservableObject.

Comment: It doesn't currently work with a binding to an ObservableObject's published array (the detail doesn't update). Only binding into state array works for some reason.

Comment: @Asperi can you show example how to refresh ChildDetailView ?

Comment: @Asperi I found that in iOS17.2 this code requires that Binding<Int> is conformed to `Hashable`

Answer (score 10):

The Foodtruck sample app from Apple has an example on how to tackle bindings in a navigationDestination. Have a look at the [following line in their github repo](https://github.com/apple/sample-food-truck/blob/4b63f0841af4e6656e9ad6a0294fdcab4a5f077b/App/Donut/DonutGallery.swift#L63)

```swift
        .navigationDestination(for: Donut.ID.self) { donutID in
            DonutEditor(donut: model.donutBinding(id: donutID))
        }
```

They use the Donut model ID for navigation. To pass on the binding, they [added a getter/setter on the FoodTruck model](https://github.com/apple/sample-food-truck/blob/4b63f0841af4e6656e9ad6a0294fdcab4a5f077b/FoodTruckKit/Sources/Model/FoodTruckModel.swift#L170) that contains a list of donuts to generate a binding by Donut.ID.

```swift
    public func donutBinding(id: Donut.ID) -> Binding<Donut> {
        Binding<Donut> {
            self.donuts[id]
        } set: { newValue in
            self.donuts[id] = newValue
        }
    }
```

Comment: This can actually be done via dollar syntax, I'm surprised the person who coded this part of Food Truck didn't know: DonutEditor(donut: $model.donuts[donutID]). In any case, using this with an @Binding in the detail, the body isn't called when it changes so Apple will have to fix this in a future beta.

Comment: I was going to implement this the way Apple did, but if you have multiple object types who use the same type for `ID`, say `Int` or `String` they will all  be bundled into the same `navigationDestination` and not their individual one.

Comment: @Darren just wrap the ID into some custom struct for each object type and it won't mess with other IDs: `struct Type1ID: Hashable { let id: Int }`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working solution, it uses the `binding(for:)` func from Apple's [ScrumDinger sample](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/passing-data-with-bindings) before they updated it to use the newer `ForEach($scrums) { $scrum`. There is something similar in the newer [Food Truck sample](https://github.com/apple/sample-food-truck) in `orderBinding(for id: Order.ID)` in but that is more verbose than the old ScrumDinger way.

Note: A strange thing is the `navigationDestination` block is called 3 times when navigating instead of once as we would expect.

```
struct NumberItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: Int
}

struct ParentListView: View {
    
    @State private var numberItems = [NumberItem(number: 1), NumberItem(number: 2), NumberItem(number: 3), NumberItem(number: 4), NumberItem(number: 5)]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numberItems) { numberItem in
                    NavigationLink(value: numberItem.id) {
                        Text("\(numberItem.number)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: UUID.self) { numberItemID in
                ChildDetailView(numberItems: $numberItems, numberItemID: numberItemID)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildDetailView: View {
    @Binding var numberItems: [NumberItem]
    let numberItemID: UUID
    
    var body: some View {
        ChildDetailView2(numberItem: binding(for: numberItemID))
    }
    
    private func binding(for numberItemID: UUID) -> Binding<NumberItem> {
        guard let index = numberItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == numberItemID }) else {
            fatalError("Can't find item in array")
        }
        return $numberItems[index]
    }
}

struct ChildDetailView2: View {
    
    @Binding var numberItem: NumberItem
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(numberItem.number)")
            Button {
                numberItem.number += 10
            } label: {
                Text("Add 10")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the solution that you are looking for.
When you change the data in the ChildView, the data in the ParentView will be changed too. I used a different NavigationView in ParentView due to not having your package, but it's the same logic.

When you want to pass data between ChildView and ParentView (for small work), you can use @Binding type in ChildView and @State type in ParentView. Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentListView: View {

//Try this
@State var bindingData: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< 5, id: \.self) { _ in
                NavigationLink {
                    ChildDetailView(number: $bindingData) //Try this, and don't forget $ sign
                } label: {
                    Text("\(bindingData)") //Try this
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct ChildDetailView: View {

@Binding var number: Int //Try this

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(number)")
        Button {
            number += 10
        } label: {
            Text("Add 10")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this really the solution? Won't this result in a list with 5 zeroes? I want the list items to be 1 2 3 4 5, and each list item refers to it's own number. But your code inspired me to try something, I will try to keep a reference to currentNumber in the ParentView and sync them together like that! Maybe it will work

Comment: This is surely the solution. You can test it out. Whatever you add or minus in the ChildView will reflect the ParentView. If you want a variable for each list, just create 5 variables for storing data, and also naming each list at the start if you want to have a custom name like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: However, as I mentioned, this is not the best way of doing it, but it is the easiest one to learn and understand. You can try ObservedObject or Enviroment later.

Answer (score 1):

We did it! Thank you guys so much for your answers, it helped soo much! I was struggling all day with this

```swift
class NumbersService: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    func incrementByTen(index: Int) {
        numbers[index] += 10
    }
}

struct ParentListView: View {
    @StateObject var numbersService = NumbersService()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numbersService.numbers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink(value: index) {
                        Text("\(numbersService.numbers[index])")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { index in
                ChildDetailView(index: index)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(numbersService)
    }
}

struct ChildDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var numbersService: NumbersService
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text("\(numbersService.numbers[index])")
            Button {
                numbersService.incrementByTen(index: index)
            } label: {
                Text("Add 10")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I just used a shared NumbersService, and identified the selected number by index. This way both views share the same reference to the correct number, and the value correctly updates in BOTH the ParentView and ChildView! I'm not sure if this is way too complicated code, but it works for me :P

Comment: Couple of problems with this code. 1. The ForEach View needs identifiable data you can't supply indices or use id:./self because it'll crash when an item is added. 2. It's bad practice to use Combine's ObservableObject if not using combine, use a struct with a mutating func instead.