# TextField working with bound property in iOS 16 beta?

Tags: swiftui, textfield, ios16

I'm trying the iOS 16 beta, MacOS 13 beta, and Xcode 14 beta. I can't get TextField to edit a property within a @Binding struct. It works with a @State struct variable, but not binding. Anyone else seeing this problem?

I filed a Feedback with Apple a couple of days ago, but no response yet. I imagine they are swamped the week after WWDC.

- MacOS Version 13.0 Beta (22A5266r)
- Xcode Version 14.0 beta (14A5228q)

Here's a code example of the problem.

> ```
> import SwiftUI
>
> struct ContentView: View {
>     var body: some View {
>         NavigationStack {
>             List {
>                 VStack {
>                     Image(systemName: "globe")
>                         .imageScale(.large)
>                         .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
>                     Text("Hello, world!")
>                 }
>                 /// Click on Category List
>                 NavigationLink {
>                     CatList()
>                 } label: {
>                     Text("Category List")
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> struct CatList: View {
>     /// Click on bar
>     
>     @State var catArray: [Categories] = [ Categories(id: UUID(), myName: "foo"), Categories(id: UUID(), myName: "bar")]
>     
>     var body: some View {
>         List {
>             ForEach($catArray) { $eachCat in
>                 NavigationLink {
>                     CatDetails(thisCategory: $eachCat)
>                 } label: {
>                     Text(eachCat.myName)
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> struct CatDetails: View {
>     
>     @Binding var thisCategory: Categories
>     
>     var body: some View {
>         Form {
>             /// Cannot edit bar.
>             TextField("Name:", text: $thisCategory.myName)
>         }
>     }
>     
> }
>
> struct Categories: Identifiable, Hashable {
>     var id: UUID
>     var myName: String
> }
> ```

Comment: NavigationStack does not transfer bindings (see this topic for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584743/12299030. I think you mixed patterns. For `NavigationLink(destination` use `NavigationView` and it works, or if you use `NavigationStack` then use corresponding `NavigationLink(value:`+`navigationDestination`+`ObservableObject` as view model. And yes, code in question does not work at iOS 16 as well (but I did not even expect that, just in case).

Comment: Thanks. That linked post got it. I think NavigationStack is still a work in progress. Your ObservableObject idea is another working alternative.