# SwiftUI Updating the EnvironmentObject from Nested Views

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI to create a master detail view scenario. The master will display a list of tweets. The master view can alter the tweet by updating the like status. When tapped on the tweet, user is taken to the detail screen, where the user can also update the like status of tweet.

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tweets: [Tweet] = [Tweet(text: "Tweet 1", like: false), Tweet(text: "Tweet 2", like: false)]
}

struct Tweet: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    let text: String
    var like: Bool
    let id = UUID()
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        List($appState.tweets) { $tweet in
            NavigationLink(value: tweet) {
                TweetCellView(tweet: $tweet)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TweetCellView: View {
    
    @Binding var tweet: Tweet
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print(Self._printChanges())
        HStack {
            Text(tweet.text)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: tweet.like ? "heart.fill": "heart")
                .onTapGesture {
                    tweet.like.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I add a TweetDetailsScreen. Since TweetCellView expects a binding, I cannot pass simply a Tweet to the TweetCellView. I want to reuse TweetCellView and display it in the TweetDetailsScreen.

```
struct TweetDetailScreen: View {
    
    var tweet: Tweet
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print(Self._printChanges())
        VStack {
            // How can I use the same TweetCellView and allow
            // the user to update the tweet
            // The following line will give error since tweet is meant to be
            // passed as a Binding
            TweetCellView(tweet: tweet)
                .navigationTitle("Tweet Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

How can I update the tweet from inside the TweetDetailScreen, while using the TweetCellView view?

**UPDATE:**

```
@main
struct LearnApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Tweet.self) { tweet in
                        TweetDetailScreen(tweet: tweet)
                    }
            }.environmentObject(AppState())
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have to pass @Binding in the TweetCellView. If there is an easier way without passing @Binding then that is fine too.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584743/12299030?

Comment: For me if I use Binding<Tweet>.self it says Binding<Tweet> should conform to Hashable error.

Comment: Yes, you should do that - see reference to GitHub there (I just fixed link) for example.