# Why is the navigationDestination with the binding not updating properly?

Tags: swiftui, binding

Why is the binding not updating the array and the PatientView title in the ContentView?

I use the ForEach that takes a binding and the navigationDestination then passes that binding to the child view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PatientView: View {
    @Binding var patient: Patient
                
    var body: some View {
        Section("Name") {
            TextField("Name", text: $patient.name)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
        Spacer()
        .navigationTitle(patient.name)
    }
}



protocol BlankInit {
    init()
}

extension View  {
    
    func binding<V>(id: V.ID, array: Binding<[V]>) -> Binding<V> where V: Identifiable {
        if let ret = array.first(where: { $0.id == id}) {
            return ret
        } else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

}


extension Binding : Hashable, Equatable where Value: Identifiable, Value: Equatable, Value: Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: Binding<Value>, rhs: Binding<Value>) -> Bool {
        lhs.wrappedValue == rhs.wrappedValue
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)  {
        hasher.combine("Binding")
        hasher.combine(self.wrappedValue)
    }
}


struct Patient: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable, BlankInit {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var age: UInt8 = 0
    
    init(_ name: String, age: UInt8 = 0) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = 0
        self.id = UUID()
    }
    
    init() {
        self.name = ""
        self.age = 0
        self.id = UUID()
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Patient, rhs: Patient) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id  && lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.age == rhs.age
    }
            
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var appData: AppData = AppData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $appData.path) {
            List {
                ForEach($appData.patients) { $pt in
                    NavigationLink(pt.name, value: $pt)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Binding<Patient>.self) { item in
                PatientView(patient: item)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Patients")
        }
        .environmentObject(appData)
        .padding()
    }
            
}


class AppData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    @Published var patients = [Patient]()
    
    init() {
        patients.append(Patient("Smith"))
        patients.append(Patient("Jones"))
        patients.append(Patient("DeCaro"))
    }
    
}

@main
struct TestAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView() //.environmentObject(AppData())
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine if I do the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var appData: AppData = AppData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $appData.path) {
            List {
                ForEach(appData.patients) { pt in
                    NavigationLink(pt.name, value: pt)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Patient.self) { item in
                let binding = binding(id: item.id, array: $appData.patients)
                PatientView(patient: binding)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Patients")
        }
        .environmentObject(appData)
        .padding()
    }
            
}
```

It seems more 'elegant' and less kludgy to be able to do the Binding version????

Comment: Asperis answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584743/6950415) could shed some light on this.

Comment: The second way doesn't work fine if you need a TextField. If you move cursor to middle of text it jumps to end when you type.

Comment: malhal:  For me it works the same as a 'virgin' @State variable