How to pass binding to view in NavigationStack?
struct NavStack: View {
    
    @State private var memes = [MemeModel]()
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            
            VStack{
      
                Text("Pass search result")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        path.append(DataForSearch(searchTerm: "funny cats", memes: memes))
                    }
                
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0){
                    
                    ForEach(memes, id: \.memeid){ meme in
                        
                        Text(meme.title)
                    }
                }

            }
            .navigationDestination(for: DataForSearch.self){ selection in
                SearchResults(searchTerm: selection.searchTerm, memes: selection.$memes)
            }
            .onAppear{
                memes.append(MemeModel(memeid: 123, title: "meme1"))
                memes.append(MemeModel(memeid: 256, title: "meme2"))
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SearchResults: View {
    
    var searchTerm: String
    @Binding var memes: [MemeModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 50){
            Text(searchTerm)
            
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0){
                
                ForEach(memes, id: \.memeid){ meme in
                    
                    Text(meme.title)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            memes.append(MemeModel(memeid: 345, title: "meme3"))
            memes.append(MemeModel(memeid: 678, title: "meme4"))
        }
    }
}

struct DataForSearch: Hashable {
    var searchTerm: String
    @State var memes: [MemeModel]
}

struct MemeModel: Codable {
    var memeid: Int
    var title: String
}

I get the error:

Type 'DataForSearch' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable' for struct DataForSearch: Hashable

I get the fix suggestion Do you want to add protocol stubs? but I have no idea what the code is that is added with that.

You cannot have @State inside something that isn't a View.

This question has a number of answers that will be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584427/how-to-pass-binding-to-child-view-in-the-new-navigationstack-navigationdestinati

None of those answers are showing how to do that in my case. The answers only showing how to pass a single binding int and nothing aside with it
